# regex matching for whitespaces in a string fails

Tags: c, regex, if-statement, error-handling, whitespace

Suppose cli_content is " abc.txt def.txt" [note the first char is space]

The following snippet would not print error if I am passing 2 filenames. What is wrong with my regular expression?

The execution overlooks both the if statements (with regcomp and reexec) as the condition fails and simply moves on without printing error.

```
if (cli_content != NULL) {
            
            regex_t the_expression;
            //Use Extended Regular Expressions.
            
if (regcomp(&the_expression, "\\S\\s+\\S", REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
                error_msg_printer();
                regfree(&the_expression);
                return NULL;
            }

 if (regexec(&the_expression, cli_content, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
                error_msg_printer();
                regfree(&the_expression);
                return NULL;
            }
```

**Update**: I wrote a function to strip the first and last space character if present, so now I am working with a string that looks like "abc.txt def.txt". how do I setup my regex to look for multiple file names given a sinput?

Answer (score 1):

Perl backslash regex patterns (like \s and \S) are not available (normally) in POSIX extended regular expressions.  To do the equivalent in a POSIX regex, you need

```
"[^[:space:]][[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]"
```

You can [see the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), or [this helpful summary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) for more detail.